# Retrieve sharedPreferences of another application

Tags: android

I have an application( com.example.MyApplication ) which saves the current location like this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("City", city);
                editor.commit();
```

Now i would like to make another application (com.example.SecondApplication) and retrieve the city string from the other application, how can i do that?

Comment: What will SecondApplication do if MyApplication does not exist? Or existed for a while and then is uninstalled?

Comment: I think shared preferences can be accessed only within the same application but not any other application.

Comment: when retriving city i would do an if statement, if city == null then i would display a message saying the city was not saved

Comment: Shared preferences can be accessed by other applciations, shared preferences can be in private or in world readable mode, in world readable mdoe any application can access it, in private mode it can be accessed by the original apps and the apps that has the same user id

Comment: Have a glance at it http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Comment: My point is that SecondApplication needs *its own preferences* for the steady state, since MyApplication can either not be there or vanish at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a way :D
I am saving my preferences like this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("City", city);
                editor.commit();
```

I am retrieving them like this

```
Context otherAppsContext = null;
            try {
                otherAppsContext = createPackageContext("com.example.FirstApp", 0);
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            }



            SharedPreferences settings = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
            text.setText(settings.getString("City", "nope"));
```

And important, in the manifest i've put in both applications

```
android:sharedUserId="example.shared"
```

I've put it just under android:versionName